# Java how to set all data must be inserted

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
int p =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure to add this staff?","Comfirmation",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (p==0){
            String sql ="Insert into login.createstaff (Staff_ID,Staff_Name,Staff_password,Staff_Tel,Staff_position,image) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try {
                pst=conn.prepareStatement (sql);
                pst.setString(1,staffID.getText());
                pst.setString(2,staffName.getText());
                pst.setString(3,staffPassword.getText());
                pst.setString(4,staffTel.getText());
                String value =staffPosition.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pst.setString(5,value);

                pst.setBytes(6,person_image);


                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Staff Added");


            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
```

Hi all, this is my dialog to add a staff record.

But how can I set all the data that must be inserted (No data field can be empty) before I save it into the database? (I want to alert the user if he or she doesn't enter all the data.)

All data inside the database I have already set "not null" but I can still save a record even though the data is null.

Comment: are you saying you want to validate all the fields before executing the sql?

Comment: i want to set  " all " the data  must be filled before can save into database.
 For example: ID- got data but the rest are empty .Then Error message will shown.

Comment: so you want to remind the user if he or she doesn't enter all the data?

Comment: Yes ! you get what i mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `staffID.getText().trim().isEmpty()` to check if an JTextField is empty or not, using JOptionPane message dialog to remind the users. An example would be like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to add this staff?", "Comfirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (p == 0) {
        if (staffID.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {// validate user input
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter staff ID"); // remind user
        } else if (staffName.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter staff name");
        } else if (staffPassword.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter password");
        } else if (staffTel.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter staff telephone");
        } else {
            String sql = "Insert into login.createstaff (Staff_ID,Staff_Name,Staff_password,Staff_Tel,Staff_position,image) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try {
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, staffID.getText());
                pst.setString(2, staffName.getText());
                pst.setString(3, staffPassword.getText());
                pst.setString(4, staffTel.getText());
                String value = staffPosition.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pst.setString(5, value);

                pst.setBytes(6, person_image);


                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Staff Added");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```